# Getting results from 2.0 MongoDb c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-.net-driver

I have built up a sample app using both the [1.0](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.10/) and [2.0](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/R_Project_CSharpDriverDocs.htm) c# drivers for MongoDb.

They serialize the same objects and I'm able to write with both and read from the 1.0.  But I'm not able to use `FindAsync` in the 2.0 to give me any results.

Here is my 1.0 query that returns one document:

```
var results = collection.AsQueryable<FlatCatalogItem>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.BatchId == "2015.01.27" 
                                            && c.Upcs.Any(u => u.UPC == "123456803"));
```

My 2.0 query using the same data with the `FindAsync` looks like this:

```
var task = collection.FindAsync(item => item.BatchId == "2015.01.27" 
                                     && item.Upcs.Any(u => u.UPC == "123456803"));
task.Wait();
var results = task.Result;
```

The `AsyncCursor` that is returned from result has nothing in it.

```
results.MoveNextAsync().Wait(); // results.Current.Count = 0
```

This could be my ignorance with async and await, or perhaps I've missed something else with the 2.0 find methods?
Note that I do not want to use the [legacy 2.0 drivers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/2.0.0-beta1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new API is `async`-only, you shouldn't block on it. It's not scalable and could possibly lead to deadlocks. Use `async-await` all the way or keep using the old API. In an `async` method the query should look like this:

```
async Task Foo()
{
    FlatCatalogItem first = await collection.
        Find(c => c.BatchId == "2015.01.27" && c.Upcs.Any(u => u.UPC == "123456803")).
        FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // use first
}
```

Comment: Any idea why they have a FindAsync and a Find method?  Both of which have a FirstOrDefaultAsync method on them.

Comment: @runxc1BretFerrier The difference is the return value `FindAsync` returns an `IAsyncCursor` while `Find` returns `IFindFluent`. `IFindFluent` enables you to further define the search before actually doing it (for example add a projection or sort). `FindAsync` performs the query immediately and returns a cursor. You can get a cursor from `IFindFluent` with `ToCursorAsync`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this?

```
var task = collection.Find(item => item.BatchId == "2015.01.27" 
                                     && item.Upcs.Any(u => u.UPC == "123456803")).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

task.Wait();
var results = task.Result;
```

I trying to get used to the new API as well.

Comment: Still not sure how to use the async find methods, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

Or perhaps a little more elegant:

```
var result = collection.Find(item => item.BatchId == "2015.01.27" 
                                  && item.Upcs.Any(u => u.UPC == "123456803"))
                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
```

Comment: er doesn't this return the result before the async operation even completes?